# Can the comment deletion modal popup be replaced, or at least tweaked?

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, popups

Modal dialog popups have always been a great bugbear most everywhere, and it just got worse - or perhaps simply more noticeable. At least for Chrome v29.0.1547.57m, there are some changes that cause the following problems when deleting comments:

- The popup is only centred horizontally, appearing centre-top of the view port;
- the popup is blocking between windows and tabs - sure this *didn't* happen before;
- the style adjustments actually make an obviously horrible thing one has to address into a very subtle thing one has to address - there is no *ping!*, no flashing, or jumping to the thing that needs attention etc.)

[image: Modal popup in Chrome, subtle and blocking]

FireFox had altered the look of the popup a while back, though the effects are not as bad.

Hopefully these are all some manifestations of some terrible mistake that managed to get checked in and deployed and will be fixed, like, yesterday. In the meantime, and in case it *is* a design decision, can we either:

- replace it with an "in-page markup popup", or
- try to tweak it so as to at least be centre of the viewport?

Comment: Did you really want to use a screenshot that shows you downvoted a specific question? :-P

Comment: I won't even mention the permutations of words I tried when searching with no luck. Whoops. @MartijnPieters Meh. (:

Comment: The question does lack some of the other observations, however.

Comment: Voted to reopen for "replace it with an "in-page markup popup""

Comment: Given the positioning is driven by the browser, I'm pretty sure #2 is not in the powers of Stack Overflow and should be targetted to Google